# Opening a Buy / Sell position on a specific time everyday on Pine script

Tags: time, pine-script

I'm trying to create a Buy/Sell signal on 1 minute chart every day at 15:20 (time).

If 15:20 1 minute bar closes higher than 15:19 bar signal will show BUY, and if 15:20 bars close is lower than 15:19 bar's closing price then it will give a SELL signal.

I tried Time_open and time_close functions but could not achieve any result.

I'd really appreciate if anyone can help me on this

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `hour` and `minute` built-in variables to figure out if it is 15:20. Then compare the close prices of 15:20 and 15:19.

```
//@version=5
strategy("My script")

trigger_m = 20
trigger_h = 15

is_trigger_bar = (hour == trigger_h) and (minute == trigger_m)

is_buy = is_trigger_bar and (close > close[1])
is_sell = is_trigger_bar and (close < close[1])

if (is_buy)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

if (is_sell)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, really appreciate your quick response